# Using Python & Beautiful Soup, can I obtain a tag list filtered by whether background attr is set?

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I would like to obtain a list of tags from an html document, where the background attribute is set.

So for example:

```
html="<div>
    <div></div>
    <table background=\"anything\">
    </table>
</div>"

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
result = soup.findall(??)
```

In this case I would want the table tag to be present in the list. Note that the value of "anything" can be ... anything. Ideally I would like to filter the value of the background attribute based on a regex.

My question is: Can I use Beautiful Soup to obtain a list filtered on whether the value of the background attribute is set? Even better, can I filter based on a regex applied to an attribute in one step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function):

```
def has_background_attribute(tag):
    return tag.has_key('background')

soup.find_all(has_background_attribute)
```

An better alternative that also addresses your second question is ([documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments)):

```
soup.find_all(background = re.compile("your_regex"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
result = soup.findAll("", {"background": re.compile("")})
```

This also answers your second question, as you can put any regular expression in the `re.compile` statement.